# What are Object() and Object(value) for in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon such usage in [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) polyfill code:

```
var O = Object(this);
```

What are the semantics of this function? Links to documentation would be welcome too.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: `O` would be `window`.

Comment: @PHPglue Presumably, `O` would be the array on which `includes` was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Object` constructor, when called as a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object-value), attempts to convert the argument to an object, as follows:

- If the argument is already an object, it returns it.
- If the argument is object-coercible (boolean, number, string or symbol), it coerces it to an object.
- If the argument is null or undefined, or no argument is passed, it returns a new ordinary object that inherits from `Object.prototype`. Like if you used `({})`.

Examples:

```
var obj = [1,2,3], symb = Symbol();

// Object argument
Object(obj);    // obj;

// Object-coercible argument
Object(true);   // Boolean { [[BooleanData]]: true }
Object(1234);   // Number  { [[NumberData]]: 1234 }
Object("ab");   // String  { [[StringData]]: "ab", 0: "a", 1: "b", length: 2 }
Object(symb);   // Symbol  { [[SymbolData]]: symb }

// Non-object-coercible argument
Object(null);   // Object {  }
Object(void 0); // Object {  }
Object();       // Object {  }
```

The polyfill uses `Object(this)` because the spec says [`Array.prototype.includes`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes) should use [`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-toobject), but that's an internal thing which is not exposed to JS code.

Comment: I wonder why this use case was omitted at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object. Is this use case quite rare?

Comment: @SlavaSt [It's explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Description). Well, it says that it doesn't matter whether you call or instantiate it, but there is a difference if you instantiate it via a subclass.